# Possible to invoke the `animate` and define the on finish callback with one expression in native JavaScript Animation API?

Tags: javascript

As far as I fond the documentation, it looks like to define the callback for the animation, it's required to:

1. Instantiate the animation
2. Define the `onfinish` callback
3. Play the animation

Is there a way to do same things with one expression as below?

```js
Snackbar.rootElement.animate([
  {
    opacity: 1,
    transform: "none"
  },
  {
    opacity: 0,
    transform: "translateY(-200%)"
  }
], {
  duration: 500,
  easing: "ease-in"
})
   // ↓ [Warning] It just a desired syntax, NOT A VALID SYNTAX
   .onfinish(() => {
      Snackbar.rootElement.remove();
   });
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance, thank you for the comment. TypeScript tells me that syntax `onfinish?.((animaton: Animation, animationPlaybackEvent: AnimationPlaybackEvent) => {})` in invalid. I'll comment again below your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onfinish` is a setter, not a method - if you assign to it instead of calling it as a function, it'll work:

```js
console.log('start');

const d = document.createElement('div');
const res = d.animate([
  {
    opacity: 1,
    transform: "none"
  },
  {
    opacity: 0,
    transform: "translateY(-200%)"
  }
], {
  duration: 500,
  easing: "ease-in"
})
   .onfinish = (() => {
      console.log('finished');
   });
```

Another option, with `addEventListener`:

```js
console.log('start');

const d = document.createElement('div');
const res = d.animate([
  {
    opacity: 1,
    transform: "none"
  },
  {
    opacity: 0,
    transform: "translateY(-200%)"
  }
], {
  duration: 500,
  easing: "ease-in"
})
   .addEventListener('finish', () => {
      console.log('finished');
   });
```

For similar reasons, the following doesn't work:

```js
const obj = {
  set foo(arg) {
    console.log('called foo');
  }
};

obj.foo(123);
```

The setter can be invoked by assigning to it, but not by calling it as if it was a function (even though it *is* a function internally).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Second solution works fine. According the TypeScript types definitions, the `onfinish` could be the `null` (`onfinish: ((this: Animation, ev: AnimationPlaybackEvent) => any) | null;`) and in my case it's such as.